# $f:A \to B$ is a function. Show that if the right inverse is unique, then the left inverse is also unique.

Tags: functions

I tried through contradiction.

Assume there are $h_1$, $h_2 :A \to B$ such that for all $x \in A$, I have $h_1(f(x)) = x = h_2(f(x))$. And show the right inverse $g:B \to A$ is not unique. Also I know that $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y \in B$.

The only thing coming to mind is, applying $h_1,h_2$ to $f(g(y)) = y$. So $h_1(f(g(y)))=h_2(f(g(y))) \implies h_1(y) = h_2(y)$. But this gets me nowhere.

Comment: If it has a left and right inverse, then they are equal and unique, because then $f$ is an isomorphism. You proved that $h_1,h_2$ are equal, using a similar argument you can prove that the left inverse and right inverse coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h_1(y) = h_2(y)$ for all $y \in B$ in your attempt is equivallent to $h_1 = h_2$ by the definition of the mapping. Since we can take left inverses $h_1$ and $h_2$ arbitrary, it follows that the left inverse is unique, though we did not lead a contradiction in this proof.

You must suppose $h_1 \neq h_2$ to lead a contradiction, which is equivalent to $h_1(y) \neq h_2(y)$ for some $y \in B$ (and it is converse to your result).